# Capturing mixed content in XML using a SAX Parser

Tags: java, xml, sax

Is a SAX Parser capable of capturing mixed content within an XML document (see example below)?

`<element>here is some <b>mixed content</b></element>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. You get the following events:

1. startElement (element)
2. characters ("here is some ")
3. startElement (b)
4. characters ("mixed content")
5. endElement (b)
6. endElement (element)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although I'm not sure what you mean by *capturing*.  If you run the short example below, you'll see the *startElement* handler called for both *element* and *b*:

```
String xml = "<element>here is some <b>mixed content</b></element>";
SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new DefaultHandler(){
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("Started: "+name);
    }
});
```